# Cannot find the API to submit a survey response to surveymonkey

Tags: api, survey, surveymonkey

I need to submit a survey response from my own mobile app. The user will be shown a survey to fill for which i can pull the survey questions and answer choices using the get_survey_details api call but how do I submit the response to survey monkey? I dont see a submit_survey type api call anywhere. I this API is available on certain plan I can arrange for that plan but I just need to know before I pay for a plan and later find that I cannot submit response from my mobile app.

I looked here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api_console

And in the documentation: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/requests_responses

*P.S. I'm planning to use the platinum plan as it allows me to send custom variables to the survey which I will use later for analytics.*

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't seen it already, API V3 is released. See the docs on responses: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#survey-responses

Answer (score 0):

Nigel is correct. API V2 does not provide way to submit responses. A new version of the API is in the works, and will provide additional functionality. Updates will be posted at https://developer.surveymonkey.com/.

Answer (score 0):

My client has specified an app that has their Survey Monkey surveys embedded so that app users (Members) can be notified of new surveys and answer surveys all within their iOS or Android app.

As I look at the problem, I need API methods to be able to:

1. View the surveys available to Members and their completion status
2. Get the questions from the Survey and present them for entry
3. Submit the answers entered from the Survey

Will this functionality be available in API V3?  What is the timeframe for this new API?  The app has other means of notifying the users, so potentially we can do that in the interim and direct them to web pages to complete the survey, but ultimately we want it all within the app.